# Why does this code gives me the error "imageicon cannot be converted to int"?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, imageicon

I have a problem with adding a picture to my messagescreen. The code works if I don't use textfields in my box, but it also worked with the textfields and without the picture... I really don't get why I'm getting this error:

> incompatible types: ImageIcon cannot be converted to int

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Input{    

    public static String[] geefInputNamen(){    
        JTextField veld1 = new JTextField(); 
        JTextField veld2 = new JTextField();

        Object[] velden = {  
            "Speler 1:", veld1,
            "Speler 2:", veld2
        };

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("nbalivemobile.png");

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, velden, "Spelers vergelijken", 
                                   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, icon);


        String[] namen = new String[2];

        namen[0] = veld1.getText(); 
        namen[1] = veld2.getText();

        return namen;
    }   
}
```

I'm new here, so I hope this is posted right. :)

Comment: Which line produces this error?

Comment: line 18 produces the error.

Comment: I have no clue which one is that...

Comment: starting with joptionpane, but the question is already answered below

Comment: @PieterDeSmet, `but the question is already answered below` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an `Icon` to `showConfirmDialog`, you need to [use the 6 argument overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-):

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    null,
    velden,
    "Spelers vergelijken",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, // Add this argument
    icon);
```

I've used `PLAIN_MESSAGE` in this example, but you can use any one of `ERROR_MESSAGE`, `INFORMATION_MESSAGE`, `WARNING_MESSAGE`, `QUESTION_MESSAGE`, or `PLAIN_MESSAGE` as specified in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a parameter in your call to JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog, messageType which is an int and goes between optionType and icon. See the doc for [JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon))